# WKWebView ImagePicker catch event of choosing of picture iOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, wkwebview

I'm working with WKWebView on which I'm tapping 'Load file'. WKWebView opening for me UIImagePickerView during which I need to know - what image was choosen.

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller?changes=_8 or some tutorials like https://makeapppie.com/2016/06/28/how-to-use-uiimagepickercontroller-for-a-camera-and-photo-library-in-swift-3-0/ What have you tried already?

Comment: Read docs many times. Tried to catch link via decidePolicyFor func of navigationDelegate.
Didn't catch it.

Actually - I can't find access to UIImagePickerView inside WKWebView which makes no sense :(

Comment: Provide enough code to replicate your scenario so it'll be easy for someone to test your logic and provide a solution

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me.

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if let imagePicker = viewControllerToPresent as? UIImagePickerController {
        previousIPDelegate = imagePicker.delegate
        imagePickerController = imagePicker
        imagePickerController?.delegate = self
    }

    super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
```

After this - you'll be able to work with didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo func where you can catch and work with chosen media, should return old delegate to imagePicker and call didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo func in old delegate

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var newInfo = info
    if let pickedImage = newInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        /// DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    }

    picker.delegate = previousIPDelegate
    previousIPDelegate?.imagePickerController!(picker, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: newInfo)
}
```

You should do the same in DidCancel func

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.delegate = previousIPDelegate
    previousIPDelegate?.imagePickerControllerDidCancel!(picker)
}
```

Comment: this worked great, thank you so much, saved me a lot of time!

Comment: In my case it was a complicated scenario, as I am opening a camera from Froala editor on WKWebView, but your solution shown me a way, thanks a lot!

Comment: what is "previousIPDelegate" ?